# Blender Python Propertygroup update

Tags: python, add-on, properties

I try to define five variables (called weights) with Propertygroups
and a function to be notified if the Floatporperty-sliders have been moved:

```
def weightUpdate():
  print(f"update----------------------{time.time()}" )

class My_Settings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
  wgt1: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
     name='wgt1',
     default=0.0,
     update = weightUpdate()
  )
  wgt2: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
     name='wgt2',
     default=0.0,
     update = weightUpdate()
  )
  wgt3: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
     name='wgt3',
     default=0.0,
     update = weightUpdate()
  )
  wgt4: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
     name='wgt4',
     default=0.0,
     update = weightUpdate()
  )
  wgt5: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
     name='wgt5',
     default=0.0,
     update = weightUpdate()
  )
```

The registration seems to work:

```
 def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(My_Settings)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=My_Settings)
```

And in the draw function of my main addon-class I also could define the slider, even in a loop for all five sliders:

```
def draw(self, context):
...
 for i in range(0,N):
      row = layout.row()
      wTxt = f"wgt{i+1}"
      row.label(text=wTxt)
      row = layout.row()
      row.prop(my_tool, wTxt)
```

The problem:

The function weightUpdate is only called when the script is started for the first time. Although any slider change is printed into the Python console in Blender, the function is not called again.

Also, is there a way to pass parameters to the update-function, like  update = weightUpdate(3) for the third wgt-slider
to identify which slider was changed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you initialize your `bpy.props.Property` attributes, you assign what's on the right side of the equal sign to the attribute that's on the left side.

If you assign `update` to `weightUpdate()`, you're not assigning the *function*  `weightUpdate`, but the *result* of this function, which is `None`, the default implicit return value of a function.

That's why the print is done once on registering, and never again. The function is called only once and the result is stored in the update callback, but since it's `None`, it might as well not exist.

What you want to assign `update` to is the *function* :

`update=weightUpdate`

But even then the code will throw an error, because [according to the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatProperty) :

> This function must take 2 values (self, context) and return None

The two parameters will be automatically provided by Blender at runtime when the update is fired. Here, `self` will be the object that's holding the property, so the instance of My_Settings that's tied to your scene. `context` will be the context at the time the update is fired.

So a stripped down soluton would be :

```
def weightUpdate(self, context):
  print(self)
  print(context)
  print(f"update----------------------{time.time()}" )
  
class My_Settings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
  wgt1: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
     name='wgt1',        
     default=0.0,
     update = weightUpdate
  )
# etc.
```

Now let's say you want to use only one update function, but you want it to behave differently whether you update value1, or value2, etc.

You can use a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=lambda#lambda) to set up additional parameters.

```
def weightUpdate(self, context, index):
  print(f"Weight {index} was updated")
  print(f"update----------------------{time.time()}" )
  
class My_Settings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
  wgt1: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
     name='wgt1',        
     default=0.0,
     update= lambda self, context: weightUpdate(self, context, 1)
  )
  wgt2: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
     name='wgt2',
     default=0.0,
     update= lambda self, context: weightUpdate(self, context, 2)
  )
# etc.
```

In this case the lambda is a new object that's not evaluated directly on creation. It can be called and evaluated at runtime, that's why you can call `weightUpdate(self, context, index)`.

A minimal working example :

```
import bpy

def weightUpdate(self, context, index):
  print(f"Weight {index} was updated")
  
class My_Settings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
  wgt1: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
     name='wgt1',        
     default=0.0,
     update= lambda self, context: weightUpdate(self, context, 1)
  )
  wgt2: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
     name='wgt2',
     default=0.0,
     update= lambda self, context: weightUpdate(self, context, 2)
  )
  
class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        my_tool = context.scene.my_tool 
        for i in range(0,2):
           row = layout.row()                
           wTxt = f"wgt{i+1}"
           row.label(text=wTxt)
           row = layout.row()                
           row.prop(my_tool, wTxt)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(My_Settings)    
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=My_Settings)     
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

BTW, the standard number of space indentation usually used is 4, not 3.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborate and detailed answer! This was very helpful to me!